# Inequality on the multinomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

Denote $N :=(n_1,n_2,..., n_s), n_j\in \mathbb{N^\ast}$ and let $k\in \mathbb{N}.$ I want to prove the following inequality

$$\sum_{|M|=k}\Big(^k_M\Big)\left[\Big(^{k+|N|}_{N+M}\Big)\right]^{-2}\leq 1,$$
where $M = (m_1, m_2, ...,m_s)$ and  $\Big(^k_M\Big)$ is the multinomial coefficient defined by $$\Big(^k_M\Big) = \frac{k!}{\prod_{k=1}^sm_k!}.$$

The simple case where $s=2$ corresponds to 
$$\sum_{m=0}^k\Big(^k_m\Big)\left[\Big(^{k+n_1+n_2}_{n_1+m}\Big)\right]^{-2}\leq 1,$$ 
which can be done by proving that
$$\Big(^k_m\Big)\left[\Big(^{k+n_1+n_1}_{n_1+m}\Big)\right]^{-1}\leq 1 \quad \text{and} \quad \Big(^{k+n_1+n_1}_{n_1+m}\Big)\geq k+1.$$ 
In this proof I used the Pascal's triangle...

Comment: In the $s=2$ case, how does $|N|$ become $n_1+n_1$? That is, what does the notation $|N|$ mean? I'd have thought it meant to sum the terms in $N,$ so that for $s=2$ case $|N|=n_1+n_2.$

Comment: This is the "length" of the multi-index $|N| = \sum_{k=1}^s n_s.$

Comment: But then in $s=2$ case, $N=n_1+n_2$ and not $n_1+n_1.$

Comment: @coffeemath Sorry it was a typo. I edited it !

Comment: I'm still confused about the denominator of the multinomial. In your general definition of a multinomial, the denominator as a usual fraction is a product of factorials of (nonnegative) integers whose sum is the integer on top whose factorial is taken in forming the multinomial. In the denominator of your expression is $n_1+m,$ making it seem at that point you interpret $N$ itself as just $n_1$ and $M$ as $m,$ if it is to fit $N+M$.

Comment: The $s=2$ case corresponds to the binomial coefficients where,for example, $\Big(^k_M\Big) = \frac{k!}{m_1! m_2!} =  \frac{k!}{m_1! (k-m_1)!} =\Big(^k_{m_1}\Big)=  \Big(^k_{m_2}\Big).$ Thus, the sum in the general case becomes $\sum_{m=0}^k... $